# Link does not jump to id when page is first loaded

Tags: hyperlink, anchor

I have a page where I've added anchor IDs at various points, and at the top of the page I created links to jump to the IDs. When I first load the page the link doesn't work, and I've determined that it's because it hasn't loaded the portion of the page that contains the section ID that it should jump to. Only after I manually scroll through the portion of the page with the ID and then scroll back to the top does the link work properly.

Is there a way to either force the page to be loaded in its entirety (not just the initially visible region of the screen) when it is first opened, so that it recognizes the IDs without needing to physically scroll to them first? Alternatively, is there a better way to handle this? I'd just like to be able to skip to the ID tags as soon as the page is loaded.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Do you use lazy loading method? I mean, Page has been loaded completely when you open it or it loads when you scroll page?

Comment: It seems to load when I scroll the page. I'm not sure how to force it to load completely.

Comment: Somewhere in your file javascript should be added. find that part and remove the link or temporarily disable javascript to solve the problem. Or if your page is online enter the website URL address to examine the codes.

Comment: Thanks very much, Zed. The page is online, but I'm not sure how I would go about examining the codes.

Comment: Could you provide us page url?

Comment: Sure, it's https://www.larrystevensband.com/copy-of-store . The "skip to merch" link is the one I'm testing.